# How to get the Current tab url from chrome using c# window application

Tags: c#-3.0

I'm trying to get URL from Current tab url which is currently opened. Is there any
way to get it? I want my application to store that address and use it
later for something useful
can anybody halp me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how far to meet your expectations.

http://watin.sourceforge.net/

Chrome only in test.

I use it for Firefox and work great. You can test your website in the new dimension.
If you modified source in simply you can open few Firefox in one time.

Comment: hi dear i already done for firefox,IE and Chrome but problem in safari and opera current url